# Android touch screen lags when connected with USB

Tags: android, usb, touch

When I connect phone to PC with miniUSB-USB cable, touch screen is behaving totally different than normally. It's like ignoring most of the touches.
For example, unlocking the screen (because of dragging a lock) is impossible.
Another example, when I want to click some button on the screen, it freaks out. It behaves like if I clicked in some other place or haven't clicked at all.
Phone's hardware buttons responds correctly.
If I plug phone out, everything is back to the normal.
The problem doesn't appear when I'm charging my phone with a charger, from the socket.
I am developing an application, so I use "USB Debugging" option. However, it doesn't matter if it's on or off, screen still lags badly.
I also noticed that my phone is automatically charging when connected to PC's USB, but it seems I cannot turn it off and I have no idea if this is the cause.

Anybody knows what's wrong or how to fix it?

Samsung Galaxy Mini (GT-S5570)
Android 2.2.1

Comment: Have you tried to gdb the kernel usb stack? I'd start looking there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try a different cable or a different port. I've had this kind of trouble with my device on certain USB chargers and I've been told it's because of grounding or something electrical like that. never had any trouble with a cable to a PC though.

Comment: I've tried 2 cables with 3 ports and... It works if and only if the internet cable is plugged out! There are other cables like mouse or microphone, but they're not doing harm. Only this 3m cable to the modem... Thanks for the clue!

Answer (score 1):

it's because of electric noise.... make sure your computer is connected to ground (earth)

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem, In my case when i Increased the brightness to Maximum (Same Cable, Same Port, same phone) my Issue was resolved at much extent.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly because of the power issue.Your PC is not giving the mobile device the correct power it needs ,so resulting in over or under values to the touch display .Thats why the display does not correspond to the correct touch signal .Check on the power issues or else possibly ur display has some errors .